# Hang Man Game in MVC with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to create Hang man game, but I need to save the session and the username, but I have problems for pass the username. I wrote the JSP, servlet and Javabean, but after the login my user, in the next view I only have Welcome + NULL. Help me please. thanks for the help.

I don't know how Can I pass the name to the next view.

```
enter code here
```

---

this is the JavaBean(**Userdata.java**):

```
public class Userdata {

String userName;

public Userdata() {
}

public Userdata(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

---

This is the servlet, in this code I need to use a session, but I want to that, in all the time that the user is logging, cans see his/her name

**loginServlet.java**

```
public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws     
ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  
ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    Userdata = new Userdata(usuari);

    if(request.getParameter("username")!=null &&
           !request.getParameter("username").trim().equals("") ){
       usuari = new Userdata(request.getParameter("username"));
    }

    if(request.getParameter("logout")!=null){
        session.invalidate();
    }   

    request.setAttribute("username", username);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("juego.jsp");
    view.forward(request, resp);
}
}
```

---

Finally the Views in JSP,  The first view is the login

Nom de jugador:
            
            
            
            Contrasenya:

And this is the response of servlet -> juego.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Penjat</title>    

   </head>

    <h2>Benvingut</h2> 

   <%=request.getAttribute("usuari")%>

<div align="center">
    <h1>Joc del Penjat</h1>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <!--Delaració d'imatges-->
    <img src="Imatges/p_JEE_3.png">
</div>

<div align="center">    
    <!--Declaració de les lletres-->
    Lletra:
    <input type="text" name="lletra" size="1" maxlength="1">
    <br/>
   <p>
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value=""/>
       <input type="hidden" name="vegades_jugades" value=""/>
       <input type="hidden" name="pistes" value=""/>          
       <input type="submit" name="boto_jugar" value="Jugar">
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to put username in request, in your servlet use request.setAttribute in the following manner

```
request.setAttribute("username", value);
```

where value happens to be the object you want to read later.

Use it later in a different servlet/jsp using request.getAttribute as

```
String value = (String)request.getAttribute("username")
```

or

```
<%= request.getAttribute("username")>
```

Comment: If You have a problem, please create an appropriate question, add source code and description. One line of comment is not enough to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, now I understand, I modificated and now I can get the username.

*@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws

    ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();*

```
    Userdata usuari = new Userdata();

    if(request.getParameter("username")!=null &&
           !request.getParameter("username").trim().equals("") ){
       usuari = new Userdata(request.getParameter("username"));
    }

    if(request.getParameter("logout")!=null){
        session.invalidate();
    }   

    request.setAttribute("username", usuari);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("juegoOriginal.jsp");
    view.forward(request, resp);
}
```